# Docker mount only works in interactive mode

Tags: docker, containers, mounted-volumes

I'm new to Docker and I am trying to use the mount options of the run command, but they're not working in my linux environemnt.

I have an executable called *transformer*, whose purpose is taking a txt file from a directory called *txts*, transform it into a python file and save such file into another directory called *dict*.
On top of these 2 folders, I have a third one (lib) containing the libraries required to launch transformer.

So the structure of my project folder is as such:

```
* folder txts
 |
 |__ myfile.txt
* folder dict
* folder lib <contains some cpp libraries>
* executable transformer
* Dockerfile
Path to this directory: /home/ec2-user/MyDockerTests/transformerproject/
```

Running transformer requires launching the following command:

```
./transformer -d <path to the txt file> -o <path where you want to save the newly created python file>
```

With this, I tried running the process inside a Docker container.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine
FROM gcc

COPY . /usr/project/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/project/lib

WORKDIR /usr/project/

CMD ./transformer -d txts/myfile.txt -o dict/mytransformedfile.py
```

And with this I built the image calling it *transformercontainer*

```
docker build --tag transformercontainer .
```

However, obviously, the container runs, does its thing, immediately stops afterwards and I'm left without my python file, so the next step would be linking the dict folder of the container to the dict folder of the host machine. And here's where I keep failing.

I launch the following command:

```
docker run -v /home/ec2-user/MyDockerTests/transformerproject/dict/:/usr/project/dict/ transformercontainer
```

And the python file doesn't appear inside my host machine dict folder.

What I did then was trying to manually launch the transformer executable inside the container by running it in interactive mode

```
docker run -it -v /home/ec2-user/MyDockerTests/transformerproject/dict/:/usr/project/dict/ transformercontainer
```

At this point I ran the *same exact command* I wrote in the CMD portion of the Dockerfile directly, and now not only I can clearly see that, inside the container, the dict folder is now populated with a new python file, but when I close the container I can also find that same python file inside my host machine's dict folder, so the directory mount worked just fine.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong but after countless attempts I'm at my last straw.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems ok apart from the quote in `CMD "./transformer -d txts/myfile.txt -o dict/mytransformedfile.py`

Please try:
`CMD ./transformer -d txts/myfile.txt -o dict/mytransformedfile.py`

Comment: Do you navigate the directories before running your "transformers" command in the docker interactive mode?

Comment: No, I'm already brought to the correct directory, I suppose that means the WORKDIR command is working correctly

Comment: This is probably the last thing in mind as nothing seems wrong apparently :) Have you built the image from scratch after removing the quote typo? If not, then try doing it.

Comment: I did that too. Deleted the already "exited" container, deleted the image and then built it anew. I've just read that besides CMD there's also the ENTRYPOINT command, I'll try that one too